# Footer on middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to find a way to keep my footer at the bottom of the page when the user zooms to or so 25%. But keep it in the right place when the user has the default zoom. I can just delete the whole footer section and it works for default zoom. I've been reading a lot but can't seem to get it working.

Here are some screenshots of what I mean:

[image]

[image]

```
.footer {
    background-color: #171717;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px 0;
    margin-top: -3em;
}
```

More context:

```
html {
    height: 100% !important;
}

body, html {
    position: relative !important;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    color: #838282;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

I am using bootstrap. Please, any idea is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try getting rid of the position absolute on the footer as well as the bottom:0. If that doesn't work, do you mind posting the HTML as well?

Comment: I know some people hate it, but have you tried position fixed instead? Else a javascript solution to affix to the bottom?-- i think your issue is the body area is taller than the browser window and you have made the body no overflow so your absolute ends up being the browser height or something instead of the content.

Comment: it's impossible to say what's wrong without seeing your html code as well as css.

Comment: @T.Chmelevskij I'd just say upload everything to a webserver so we can access it and attempt to find out what's wrong.